# Uncrustify align trailing comments?

Tags: c++, c, comments, uncrustify

Is there a way to go from the below

```
int a; ///< This is a variable
int b = 3; ///< This is another variable
```

To the below?

```
int a;      ///< This is a variable
int b = 3;  ///< This is another variable
```

Comment: Do you mean some script or editor (for eg: vim) shotcut

Comment: perhaps see if `align_right_cmt_span` helps

Comment: @TheBadger, `align_right_cmt_span` is what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: @AyberkÖzgür I have posted it as an answer if you are willing to accept it

Comment: I assume the downvotes are for not reading the documentation.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, well, the documentation doesn't contain the IMHO crucial keyword `trailing`, hence the reason I was not able to quickly find it. I don't think this question deserves a downvote since it links this keyword to `align_right_cmt_span`.

Comment: @AyberkÖzgür: Good thing I upvoted it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align_right_cmt_span` should be the correct setting.